# How can I store and query 50 million simple Python dicts?

Tags: python, ubuntu, nosql

### Question

Each dict has a unique numeric id field but the rest are variable (all text or numeric values though). Some simple query functionality would be nice e.g. `get where name contains 'abc'` or `where a < 123`.

What are my options?

### Setup

- Python 2.6
- 32-bit Ubuntu-server 256MB
- single machine
- no swap

example dict:

```
{'id': 3823942, 'name': u'example', 'unknown_variable_key': u'foo'}
```

### Notes

can't use MongoDB: 32-bit MongoDB processes are limited to about 2.5 gb of data
can't use Redis because it needs the whole dataset in RAM

Comment: Is the set of possible dictionary keys known in advance?  Could you be a bit more specific on how the dicts look like (perhaps with an example)?  What kind of queries do you need?

Comment: @Sven Marnach: no it's not known and I don't *need* any queries beyond at least being able to read back the data for an id quickly.

Comment: why is it that you don't consider http://www.sqlite.org/ ie why the solution must be nosql?

Comment: I don't want to manually create and alter tables. I thought there might be something better suited than sqlite.

Comment: This fails your 'query functionality' test, but I've had good results from python's builtin 'shelve' module. Acts like a dict, but it's on disk. You could store your little dicts in the shelve. Pick your shelve keys intelligently though, you don't want to be searching the shelve if you can help it.

Comment: Oh, and make sure you close your shelves, they don't always write to disk when you think they should. Maybe the 'with' statement is enough to ensure shelve closing?

Comment: @2371, well in one way or another you have to define your data structures... I am still like you to further refine your requirements: do you need great structure flexibility (changing schema/unknown schema), highest possible performance for certain tasks, flexibility with querying, stability.. (which of these are priority? feel free to add your own...). Finally re creating your own tables, there are wrappers such as http://sqlobject.org/ that'll do that for you

Comment: Have you looked into redis with VM enabled? Only the keys actually need to be permanently in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using CouchDB. It's a document-oriented database. There are examples (e.g. [here](http://www.couch.io/migrating-to-couchdb)) of storing millions and more documents.

There is a [good guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/index.html) to CouchDB.

Your numeric id field can be used as a document id.

You can try writing a python script that fills the database using [bulk APIs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API) (to make insertion of that number of objects faster)

Views can be used to make various queries.

**[edit]**

I was curious about CouchDB memory consumption and made a simple experiment.

I've inserted 5kk documents in chunks of 50k docs in an empty database. It took about 15-20 minutes on my Code Duo MacBook. During the insertion maximum memory consumption by the CouchDB process was 120MB when inserting 50k docs in a chunk and around 60MB when inserting 25k chunks.

Final database size is around 1.2GB. Memory consumption of the idle CounchDB process is 40MB. Fetching single documents is instantaneous (using the Futon web frontend).

I was inserting documents of the following format (JSON generated with Python):

```
'{"_id" : "%09d", "name" : "example", "field%d" : "hello"}' % 
    (num, random.randint(0, 100))
```

or

```
{"_id" : "005049980", "name" : "example", "field77" : "hello"}
```

The `_id` is used as a key and documents are sorted by that key.

About sample queries that you've provided. The are not efficient because in general you need to traverse the whole document set to get the result. But both can be optimized after creating special views.

Comment: One concern is the revisions feature, it seems like it'll consume a lot of disk space. Maybe you'd be interested in seeing what happens if you update all those documents once.

Comment: Actually it's not a feature, it's how the storage is implemented: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/btree.html  I don't want to test because I'm sure that it will become at least two times larger. And I can't imagine why do you need to update all the documents. If you'll write more about your problem, it would be possible to estimate better how well CouchDB suits your needs.

Comment: I'm constantly updating documents, not every single one at once obviously, I wanted to see how that affected the disk usage. I've started adding data now anyway, I'll report back later.

Comment: @2371 ok, then you can just use Compaction http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Compaction from time to time. It's a background operation which cleans up old revisions and other garbage.

Comment: I'm somewhat regretting using CouchDB. The compaction is terribly slow and without it the disk use grows and grows. Also there are CPU use issues and sometimes connection errors.

Comment: Note that the link given in the answer is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Pytables might be an option for you http://www.pytables.org/moin

Comment: Given that the OP said he's only interested in storing numeric and character data (i.e. not directly storing python objects), pytables is a pretty darn good option.  It's especially good at out-of-core queries and calculations. It may or may not suit the OP's exact needs, but either way, +1 from me.

Comment: On second thought, I didn't read the original question fully... While HDF5 can certainly handle this sort of use case, Pytables is meant to be most efficient when querying one table... It's probably worth a try, but it's probably not the best option...

Answer (score 1):

Since the dataset is too large to be all in memory, you're most likely limited to solutions that use the disk. The simplest way to store is to serialize the dict and store as files, and there's some simple optimizations you can do for indexing so you don't have to search through the entire dataset on a query. If you have access to third-party database (mysql or even sqlite3), you can store the dictionaries into a table with columns id, key, value (so each dict maps to multiple rows in the table) and create index on id and key for queries.

Comment: sqlite works but I'm looking for a more suitable alternative where I don't have to know the column names beforehand

Comment: more information on the simple optimizations and storage would be useful

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not knowing column names beforehand .. if you have a db table with columns (id, key, value), you would map the example dict into these rows: (3823942, 'name', 'example), (3823942,'unknown_variable_key', 'foo')

Comment: A problem with this approach is the question which data type to choose for the value column.

Comment: simple solution is to always serialize the key/value to string. If the goal is to get the dict for an id quickly, he should just store as (id, serlized_dict)

Answer (score 1):

Try using littletable.  It works with a list of objects, infers column names from object attributes, and supports simple query, join, and pivot table operations.  One of the nice things is that the results of query and join operations are new, full-fledged, queryable littletables.

littletable hasn't gotten a lot of attention or use yet, so I'd be very curious to hear your feedback/experience with it.

Comment: interesting but I don't have the time to experiment much with something in alpha

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com)? It's a fast document-graph NoSQL engine, support SQL and transactions. There are no space limits on 32-bit systems even if on 64-bit is faster.

I've just tried to insert 1 million of indexed JSON documents in a fresh OrientDB database. Records are very simple:

{ 'id' : 0, 'name' : 'Gipsy', 'type' : 'Cat', 'race' : 'European', 'country' : 'Italy', 'price' : 300.00 }

But with id and price that increment by 1 at every cycle. It took 21 seconds on my 3-years old notebook. Heap memory settings are 256Mb.

The query:

SELECT from TEST where id = 30000

Took 0,01 second!

The code used for insertion has been taken from this example: http://code.google.com/p/orient/source/browse/trunk/tests/src/test/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/test/database/speed/DictionaryPutSpeedTest.java